# Css: how to map a given font to a given weight?

Tags: css, fonts

I need to assign a font to a specific weight.

AvenirNext-Regular is the base font I want. But when it comes to bold it, the result is not what I want: AvenirNext-Bold is too heavy. I'd like to use AvenirNext-DemiBold instead.

Is there a cool way to assign Semibold (or whatever font I need) to the font-weight: bold property?

[EDIT] I tried to explore the following, but is there a way to add src for an existing font-face?

@font-face {
    font-family: "AvenirNext-DemiBold";
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: A text-shadow might do.

Answer (score 2):

To use your semi-bold font on all the `font-weight: bold` assignments, just search and replace in your CSS for `bold` to say `600` (or whatever value will equal your Semibold font).  This only works if the Semibold version of the font is included with the family (aka, downloaded by the browser or already on the user's PC).

`bold` in CSS is actually a variable keyword that maps directly to a font-weight of `700`.  `normal` goes to `400` and a couple others exist, as you can see here in the article below:

### [CSS-Tricks article on font-weight](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/)

*PS - though not a requirement, but for control, I think it's much better to use the weight values literally than to use them with english words.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `font-weight: 600;` which is semi bold.

I could be wrong however, this issue seems to be more relevant towards your custom font you're loading to the page as I noted "AvenirNext-Regular" and "AvenirNext-Bold".

As you've stated you want DemiBold - is there such custom font with the weight embedded into the font?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doing this make impossible to set arbitrary font-family as you have to know whether a demi bold version is available. I really intent to attach a given font to bold and the HTML/CSS code doesn't have to be altered.